# В каких словах есть 2 или 3 суффикса

Tags: словообразование

В каких словах есть 2 или 3 суффикса

Comment: @Nadya, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Например, читал - глагольный суффикс А, суффикс прошедшего времени Л. Испачкавшийся - глагольный суффикс А, суффикс причастия ВШ, возвратный суффикс СЯ. Сколько нужно слов? Можно заглянуть в словообразовательный или морфемный словарь.

Answer (score 2):

млад/енч/еств/о

за/кат/и/ть/ся

за/град/и/тель/н/ый

граб/и/тель/ск/ий